# Is this dead code, redundant code or usefull code?

Tags: redundancy, dead-code

Let's say you have an application in which module A provides the service SRVA.

You also have modules B and C that use SRVA according to the spec.
Finally you have modules D and E that shouldn't use SRVA according to the spec.

Then you have 2 modes M1 and M2. And the spec says that the functionality handled by SRVA must not be executed during M1.

So here is my question. **Would you add some code preventing the execution of SRVA during M2 *everywhere*?**

I mean, if you include the following piece of code in *module B and C*:

```
if(SRVA needed & !M1)
{
  request SRVA
}
else
{
  error
}
```

and the following code in *module A*:

```
if(SRVA requested & !M1)
{
  service SRVA
}
else
{
  error
}
```

Do you consider this is dead code or redundant code?
In other word, do you consider this as a bad practice?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Dead code can be useful code, at least to your colleague developers

Comment: Ok. Then are you aware of a "coding standard" that forbid dead code? I am thinking to things like SIL (Safety Integrity Level), etc. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but then you wrap it with `#if 0`, or commit it to version control, etc...

Comment: So, in this case, only one "request validator" is used. Do you mean that SIL forbids dead code? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So here is my question. Would you add some code preventing the execution of SRVA during M2 everywhere?

**Yes**, absolutely. If I receive a requirement in the form

> the functionality handled by SRVA must not be executed during M2.

I will honour it by coding this behaviour.

But please *revise the pseudocode you wrote* as it seems to work the opposite way.

Comment: I revised the pseudocode, nice catch :)! Same question as above: are you aware of a "coding standard" that forbid dead code? I am thinking to things like SIL (Safety Integrity Level), etc. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't have to follow any standard forbidding dead code. But when working in open source projects I have received the "suggestion" to lint the code before submitting...and lint tools usually warn you about that

Comment: Thanks for the details. I accepted your answer since my question was not mentionning SIL in the beginning. Thanks for you help!